# Website works on one computer but not another - same browsers on both comps

Tags: website

I am on a Mac and am trying to access a website (I do not own this website) but I keep getting the error "no data received" - I tried loading the site in Chrome, Safari and Firefox but none of them load. I thought it might be a problem with their website, but my coworkers are able to access the site no problem - we tried it on Macs and PCs.

I cleared the cache, reset the history, checked my Internet connection, etc.

Is there anything I'm missing? What could be the problem? I have never run into this before.

Let me know if there's any information I didn't include here that would be helpful to solve this problem. I have never run into this issue before and don't have the same problem with any other website.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is it a Wordpress site?

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a Linux Live USB flash drive a la
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/

(I'd use the 64-bit version of Xubuntu from http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/, not Ubuntu; shorter learning curve)

- and test site access with Firefox. Does it work?

If so, then check your hosts file from a terminal window with

*sudo nano /private/etc/hosts*

and see if there's a listing there for the website's domain. If so, comment out that line.

You can also add lines to it, if, oh, say, you want to block a web advertiser, e.g.,

127.0.0.1  BC.YAHOO.COM

More on the function of the Hosts file is explained at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)